# if $1>\delta>0$ and $|z-(-i)|<\delta$, then $|z|>1-\delta$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

if $1>\delta>0$ and $|z-(-i)|<\delta$, then $|z|>1-\delta$.

Drawing the graph, it is easy to see that this statement is true. I cannot, however, show this algebraically using inequalities and basic properties of complex numbers.

Comment: reverse triangle inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $|z+i| > |i| - |z|$. Can you finish it now?